# How do I allow spaces to be read during execution?

Tags: c, string, string-comparison

The program is to compare the string but however there's a problem with the spacing when I execute it. As I input the first string with spacing, the program just jump to comparing the strings, not allowing me to input the second string as follows:

```
>>"Enter first string":
"Hello Hey"
">>Enter second string:"
">>First string is more than the second string."
```

[image: screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h>

int main (void) {

    int result; //store results
    char input1[50];
    char input2[50];

    printf("Enter first string:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",input1);

    printf("Enter second string:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",input2);

    result = strcmp(input1, input2);

    if (result==0)
        printf("First string is equal to second string\n");

    if (result>0)
        printf("First string is greater than second string\n");

    if (result<0)
        printf("First string is less than the second string\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"%[^\n]s"` --> `"%49[^\n]%*c"`

Comment: Don't post images of text! It was really easier to post an image than copy/pasting the text directly??

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 's answer was a great help. The program is working now! Thanks!
Thanks all of you for answering my question. It really helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it with the `stdlib.h` with this function:

```
gets(input1);
gets(input2);
```

For sure, the `POSIX` way will work, you can use read to get the line from stdin:

```
read(STDIN_FILENO, input1, 50)
```

Comment: Avoid using `gets`, it is depricated and dangerous as it has no way to tell how long string input to accept.

Comment: Also, `gets` is not in `stdlib.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Add spaces:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]s",input1); 
scanf(" %[^\n]s",input2);
```

It will consume all the white spaces encountered in previous inputs.

When you enter any input, you also enter a new line character (white space) with your input. And that newline character is being read by second `scanf` in your code.

**The Question:**

> How do I allow spaces to be read during execution? (*the question*)

You are already doing it using `[^\n]` in `scanf("%[^\n]s",input1);` which means to read the input until a new line (`\n`) is encountered. Also, not that `\n` itself doesn't get read in this way.

**Output:**

```
Enter first string:
Strings in C
Enter second string:
Strings in C
First string is equal to second string
```